# React Navigation v.5 configuring the correct state object for deep links

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, deep-linking, stack-navigator

I have an issue when handling deep links in my app. I believe my config variable which I pass to [useLinking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-linking) is incorrect. My navigation structure is as follows:

App.js (simplified)

```
const App = () => {

    const {state} = useContext(UserContext);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
    const [initialState, setInitialState] = React.useState();
    const ref = React.useRef();

    const config = {
        Home: {
          path: 'home',
          screens:{
            HomeDetails: {
              path: 'details/:id',
              parse: {
                id: Number
              }
            },
            ContentPlay: {
              path: 'content/:cid',
              parse: {
                cid: Number
              }
            }
          }
        }
    };


    const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
        prefixes: ['http://example.com', 'https://example.com'],
        config
    });



    useEffect(() => {
        getInitialState()
        .catch(() => {})
        .then(state => {
            if (state !== undefined) {
                setInitialState(state);
            }
            setIsReady(true);
        });
    }, [getInitialState]);


    if (!isReady){
        return <LoadingScreen />;
    }
    return (
       <NavigationContainer ref={ref} initialState={initialState} >
           {state.user.token === '' ? <LoginStack/> : <MainStack/>}
       </NavigationContainer>
   );
};
```

MainStack.js (simplified)

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNav() {

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator 
          initialRouteName='Home'
          drawerContent={props => CustomDrawerContent()}>
        <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={HomeScreen}/>
        <Drawer.Screen 
          name="Content" 
          component={ContentScreen}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

const MainStack = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="DrawerNav">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="DrawerNav"
          component={DrawerNav}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeDetails"
          component={HomeDetailsScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ContentPlay"
          component={ContentPlayScreen}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}


export default MainStack;
```

The way my navigation is setup, the user can switch back and forth between the Home and Content screens via drawer nav. From Home, the user can push the HomeDetails screen onto the stack. From HomeDetails, they can only go back (pop) to Home. They cannot navigate to the Content or ContentPlay screens. Similarly, from Content, the user can push the ContentPlay screen onto the stack. From ContentPlay they can only go back to Content.

My issue is that I can't get any deep link to navigate to HomeDetails or ContentPlay, with either Home or Content at the root of the navigation stack. I think my config is wrong. The [react-navigation documentation on deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking#example-app) states that "It's important to note that the state object must match the hierarchy of nested navigators. Otherwise the state will be discarded."

I have also tried another config value which does deep link to HomeDetails or ContentPlay, but when the app is cold-opened (has been killed), it puts those screens at the root of the navigation stack, so clicking the back button gives me a navigation error.  The config value which does this is:

```
const config = {
  HomeDetails: {
    path: "details/:id",
    parse: {
      id: Number
    }
  },
  ContentPlay: {
    path: 'content/:cid',
    parse: {
      cid: Number
    }
  }
};
```